# What is the right formula for this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of values in excel and would like to know how to do this:

There are different call numbers and each of them has a id number attatched. These call numbers can be repeated with the same Id number but others can have the same call number but different id numbers. For instance:

```
Call number     Id 
264183468      32424
264183468      32424
264183468      86323
```

Most of them have the same ID but some have different. Therefore, how can I find those calls that have different ID numbers? What is the right formula??

Thank you advance!

Comment: what kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: A list of the number of the calls that have different ID values

Comment: see https://trumpexcel.com/count-distinct-pivot-table/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula, FILTER and UNIQUE, using COUNTIFS as the criteria for the filter:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A11,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:A11,B:B,"<>"&B2:B11)>0))
```

If there is a discrepancy in the Id column the count will be greater than `0` and the filter will return the call number and the Unique will return a single list.

It will automatically spill the list down.

[image]

---

If one does not have the dynamic array formula then we must use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A2:$A$11)/((COUNTIFS(A:A,$A$2:$A$11,B:B,"<>"&$B$2:$B$11)>0)*(MATCH($A$2:$A$11,A:A,0)=ROW($A$2:$A$11))),ROW($ZZ1)))
```

Put that in the first cell and copy down.

[image]

Comment: you should keep a blog of some of your best Excel answers

Comment: Wow, impressive! Thanks a lot!